# Defining linux command in python script and able to run the command from script

Tags: scripting, python

I need to write a python script, for example I need to run the command "systemctl is-enabled autofs" and if the output the command is "Failed to get unit file state for autofs.service: No such file or directory" then the script should print "no service installed" and if the output is "enabled" then the script should run "systemctl --now disable autofs". I have tried using os and subprocess module but could not make it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with subprocess module? It can send command and read output via Popen.

Answer (score 0):

From the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) Python documentation:

> subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False,
> universal_newlines=False) Run command with arguments and return its
> output as a byte string.
>
> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The
> CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
> attribute and any output in the output attribute.

You can check the output of your initial command. Based on that, you either print `no service installed` or run `systemctl --now disable autofs`.

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_output(["systemctl", "is-enabled", "autofs"], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('no service installed')
else:
    subprocess.run(["systemctl --now disable autofs"])
```